# SwiftAutomation custom record compiler error

Tags: macos, cocoa, swift3, applescript

I'm using the [SwiftAutomation](https://bitbucket.org/hhas/swiftae) framework to drive a scriptable app that searches for lyrics and returns a AS record. Everything was working correctly, until...

I mapped the AppleScript record to a custom Swift structure according to the SwiftAutomation documentation. The code in the xxxGlue.swift file looks correct, but the compiler complains about `SwiftAutomation.SelfUnpacking`, with several follow-on errors, when building the MacOSGlues framework.

```
public struct LFBLyricsInfoRecord: SwiftAutomation.SelfPacking, SwiftAutomation.SelfUnpacking { ... }

--> .../MacOSGlues/LyricsFBAGlue.swift:700:81: No type named 'SelfUnpacking' in module 'SwiftAutomation'
```

The SelfPacking **public protocol** is defined in SwiftAutomation, and SelfUnpacking **protocol** is defined right under it, but without the *public* keyword. Is that the cause of the compiler error, and if so, how do I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I finally found a resolution. Seems you have to use different options for the aeglue utility when generating the glue file for the MacOSGlues framework and for the swift file where you actually use your automation, such as in the test project. In my case, where my scriptable app is named LyricsFBA.app, these were:

```
aeglue -S LyricsFBA.app
```

for MacOSGlues (generates a LyricsFBAGlue.swift that references SwiftAutomation, but does not include the custom record structure definition), and

```
aeglue -D -s 'LyricsInfo:lyricsInfo=score:Int+title:String+artist:String+composer:String+link:String+lyrics:String' LyricsFBA.app
```

for the test program (generatea a LyricsFBAGlue.swift that does not reference SwiftAutomation, but does include the custom record structure definition).